# Caliburn.Micro with label not binding by convention

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have been using Caliburn.Micro's binding via convention in Silverlight 5 and am loving it.  Here is an example property from a ViewModel:

```
private String _vmStringProp = "";
public String VmStringProp
{
    get
    {
        return _vmStringProp;
    }

    set
    {
        _vmStringProp = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => VmStringProp);
    }
}
```

This property is bound in the View just by naming:

```
<TextBox x:Name="VmStringProp" />
```

This works great.  But if I change it to a TextBlock or Lable (example below) an exception is thrown.

```
<sdk:Label x:Name="VmStringProp" />
```

It works fine if you change it to bind like normal Silverlight but I would rather keep consistent throughout the project instead of having some bound via convention and others explicitly bound depending on what type of control.  Does anyone know why I can't bind via convention with Labels and TextBlocks?

Comment: You have mentioned that an exception is thrown... Can you post the exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do for that.  In my example app (regular bootstrapper) Visual Studio crashes, then asks me if I want to debug, then won't since 'a debugger is already attached'.  In my actual application my IOC MEF bootstrapper (pretty much the example Caliburn gives) throws an exception when calling GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key) since the Type passed to it is null.  It then says "Could not locate any instances of contract MyStringValueHere"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro comes with a set of default conventions for WPF/SL/WP7 but obviously not for every existing control, so the Silverlight `sdk:Label` is also missing.

You can find the built in conventions at the [end of this article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/12/16/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-7-all-about-conventions.aspx) and a lots of info how conventions work.

Luckily it is very easy to add a new convetions just add the following code into your Bootstrapper's contructor:

```
public MyBootstrapper()
{
    ConventionManager
        .AddElementConvention<Label>(Label.ContentProperty, 
                                    "Content", 
                                    "DataContextChanged");  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nemesv, that was it.  I had been concentrating on other parts of the framework and hadn't read the Caliburn stuff for a while - totally forgot about it.  I wonder why they don't add more conventions in by default - it seems like some that are missing should be default